# retrieve array values , print and substitute in URL

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I am trying to extract the value of instance from $sess_data and replace it in the URL using codeigniter.

My code is as below:

```
$uresult = $this->user_model->get_user($email, $password);

if (count($uresult) > 0) {

    // set session

    $sess_data = array(
    'login' => TRUE, 
    'uname' => $uresult[0]->fname, 
    'uid' => $uresult[0]->id, 
    'instance' => $uresult[0]->instance
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);

    foreach ($sess_data as $object) {
        echo $object->sess_data;
    }

    die;

    redirect('http://www.example.com/"instance"', 'refresh');

} else {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Email-ID or Password!</div>');
    redirect('login/index');
}
```

I need to extract this value `instance' => $uresult[0]->instance` and replace the URl instance part with this value, so that it goes to that particular URL. I am getting 5 errors withe 4 of them being Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

and 1 error saying

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Uninitialized string offset: 3
>
> Filename: controllers/login.php
>
> Line Number: 38

My Model code is :

```html
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class user_model extends CI_Model
{
 function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
 
 function get_user($email, $pwd)
 {
  $this->db->where('email', $email);
  $this->db->where('password', md5($pwd));
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
  return $query->result();
 }
 
 // get user
 function get_user_by_id($id)
 {
  $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');
  return $query->result();
 }
 
 // insert
 function insert_user($data)
    {
  return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
 }
}?>
```

Comment: can you put the model ?

Comment: Tip class naming http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: yes .. i know this.. after i solve replacing the URL with the value , i will have to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it by updating foreach loop like below..

```
foreach ($sess_data as $key => $object) {
    echo $key."=>".$object."<br />";
}
```